# How to get all keys except a certain one in Object.keys?

Tags: reactjs, key

How to get all keys except a certain one?
I want to get all the keys except "Id", how can I skip this?

My code:

```
const [newContact, setNewContact] = useState({
        id: 1,
        name: {
            value: '',
            type: "text",
            label: "Фио",
            placeholder: "Фио"
        },
        phone: {
            value: '',
            type: "text",
            label: "Номер",
            placeholder: "Номер"
        }
    });

const onHandleRenderInputs = () => {
    return Object.keys(newContact).map((input, index) => {
        const inputControl = newContact[input];
        return (
            <Form.Item label={inputControl.label} style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-start" }} key={index + input}>
                <Input
                    type={inputControl.type}
                    placeholder={inputControl.placeholder}
                    value={inputControl.value} 
                    onChange={e => onHandleSigninUserData(input, e)}
                />
            </Form.Item>
        );
    });
};
```

I create the input using Object.keys (), but I do not need all the fields, but only the "name" and "phone", how can I take only them?

Comment: When you iterate over your keys, just check the key value and if it is something you want to change, then do your logic. Otherwise, don't do anything. Or specifically search those keys on your object with [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `filter` the `Object.keys` array before mapping each item to an input control. eg.

```
const onHandleRenderInputs = () => {
    return Object.keys(newContact).filter(i=> i !== 'id').map((input, index) => {
        const inputControl = newContact[input];
        return (
            <Form.Item label={inputControl.label} style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-start" }} key={index + input}>
                <Input
                    type={inputControl.type}
                    placeholder={inputControl.placeholder}
                    value={inputControl.value} 
                    onChange={e => onHandleSigninUserData(input, e)}
                />
            </Form.Item>
        );
    });
};
```